# What could cause my MVC apps to be incredibly slow to start?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-express

Extremely often, in all kinds of various MVC3/4 apps I debug in VS2012 on my home machine, after pressing F5 to start debugging and open the configured start page in Chrome, it can take several - up to ten - minutes before becoming active.

I have no long startup procedures that load caches or generate code etc. and the same app will start instantly on my office machine. Quite often it will do so on my home machine as well, but this slow starting seems to come about after some hours of debugging, and possibly certain operations. Restarting VS doesn't seem to help, neither does killing IIS Express.

Answer (score 0):

We were faced with an identical scenario recently where attaching the application to the debugger resulted in each page load taking about 10 minutes each, but running without debugging or in the QA environment worked fine.

The problem turned out to be that log4net was configured to use a network path for storing log files, a path that was unavailable from our local setup. This resulted in multiple attempts at accessing a remote path (once for each class being set up with Spring .Net) that didn't exist (and hence log4net threw an exception in each case).

But this should impact you out of the box, and shouldn't increase with time..

Comment: I have no logging implemented yet, not even Elmah.